# Function relative to "switch" won't work

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, bots

I don't have a clue why this is not working. Everything is declared the right way, and the syntax seems perfect. 
Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
The difficulty is received from a radio selection, but I've declared it here.
The function bot won't get to the alerts.

```
    var difficulty = "easy";
    var botchance = 0;
    var botroll = 0;
    var botscore = 0;


function bot(){
    botchance =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    switch(difficulty){
    case "easy":
        if (botchance <= 6){
            botroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 3 + 1)) + 3;
        }
        else botroll=10;
        break;
    case "medium":
        if (botchance <= 7){
            botroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 2 + 1)) + 2;
        }
        else botroll=10;
        break;
    case "hard":
        if (botchance <= 8){
            botroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * (8 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        }
        else botroll=10;
        break;
    default:
        if (botchance <= 9){
            botroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        }
        else botroll=10;
    }

alert(botscore);
alert(botroll);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you sure you have included all relevant code? `botscore` is not defined in the code you provided.

Comment: `It doesn't work` Always make sure to include in your question what you 1) expect to happen 2) what happened instead and usually 3) what you tried to fix it.

Comment: Why not write simple numbers (like `10`) instead of those terms (`10+1-1`)?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the developer console, you see:

`ReferenceError: botscore is not defined`

Which stops the execution and you won't see the alerts.

Comment: Yes. Always use Developer Tools like those provided with Chrome or Firebug for Firefox. It always helps in debugging and catching errors like these in an instant.

Comment: @CasmiguelF Please clarify if it was originally declared or if you just declared it after seeing my answer. If it wasn't originally declared, you are using a cached file (which can also be seen from developer tools). OTOH, If it was originally declared, your code works  as is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `alert(botscore);` or declare it;